# WooCommerce Error loading the content on Product category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating an online store using Wordpress and WooCommerce.

On administrative panel everything works fine (content loads), but if the user opens my site, he won't see the content on Shop page and Product Category pages, but content loads on the product page. So I think the problem is in permalinks. [product page loads content fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB7hk.png) [category page with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgpZH.jpg)

This is fetch request with error.

```
    fetch("http://itv.egd.mybluehost.me/wp-json/wc/store/v1/products?orderby=menu_order&order=asc&catalog_visibility=catalog&per_page=3&page=1&_locale=user", {
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json, */*;q=0.1",
            "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
            "x-wp-nonce": "15154768fa"
        },
        "referrer": "http://itv.egd.mybluehost.me/438-2/",
        "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        "body": null,
        "method": "GET",
        "mode": "cors",
        "credentials": "include"
    });
```

I noticed that if I remove `page=1`, the response from the server comes back with status 200, but I also need pagination. How can I fix that?